# Linear Regression: Finding Significant Class Variables Using SAS

Tags: sas, regression, linear-regression, p-value

I'm attempting to use SAS to do a pretty basic regression problem but I'm having trouble getting the full set of results.

I'm using a data set that includes professors' overall quality (the dependent variable) and has the following independent variables: gender, numYears, pepper, discipline, easiness, and rateInterest.

I'm using the code below to generate the analysis of the data set:

```
proc glm data=WORK.IMPORT;
    class gender pepper discipline;
    model quality = gender numYears pepper discipline easiness raterInterest;
run;
```

I get the following results, which is mostly what I need, EXCEPT that I would like to see exactly which responses from the class variables (gender, pepper, discipline) are significant. 
[image: The GLM Procedure]

[image: The GLM Procedure]

From these results, I can see that easiness, rateInterest, pepper, and discipline are significant; however, I'd like to see which specific values of pepper and discipline are significant. For example, pepper was answered as a 'yes' or 'no' by the student. I'd like to see if quality correlates specifically to pepperyes or pepperno. Can anyone give me some advice about how to alter my code to return a breakdown of the class variables?

Here is also a link to the dataset, in case it's needed for reference: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kc9cb_n-l7qwWRNfzXtZi5OsiY-gsYZC/view?usp=sharing[Rateprof](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kc9cb_n-l7qwWRNfzXtZi5OsiY-gsYZC/view?usp=sharing)

I really, truly appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `solution` option to your `model` statement to break out statistics of each class variable; however, reference parameterization is not available in `proc glm`, and will cause biased estimates. There are ways around this to continue using `proc glm`, but the simplest solution is to use `proc glmselect` instead. `proc glmselect` allows you to specify reference parameterization. Use the `selection=none` option to disable variable selection.

```
proc glmselect data=WORK.IMPORT;
    class gender(ref='female') pepper discipline / param=reference;
    model quality = gender numYears pepper discipline easiness raterInterest / selection=none;
run;
```

[image]

The interpretation of this would be:

> All other variables held constant, females affect the quality rating by
>   -0.046782 units compared to males. This variable is not statistically significant.

The breakdown of each class level is a comparison to a reference value. By default, the reference value selected is the last level after all class values are internally sorted. You can specify a reference using the `ref=` option after each class variable. For example, if you wanted to use females as a reference value instead of males:

```
proc glmselect data=WORK.IMPORT;
    class gender(ref='female') pepper discipline;
    model quality = gender numYears pepper discipline easiness raterInterest / selection=none;
run;
```

Note that you can also do this with `prox mixed`. For this specific purpose, the preference is up to you based on the output style that you like. `proc mixed` is a more flexible way to run regressions, but would be a bit overkill here.

```
proc mixed data=import;
    class gender pepper discipline;
    model quality = gender numYears pepper discipline easiness raterInterest / solution;
run;
```